# android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)

Tags: java, android, activity

Имеется элементарное незаконченное приложение: 1 лейаут-файл(activity_main.xml), 1 активность(MainActivity), 1 класс(Timer). Мне кажется причина проблемы кроется в соединении компонентов и одиночного класса. Если писать весь код в MainActivity - все запускается.

Код activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="@string/etHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:text="25:00"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartPause"
        android:text="@string/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickStartPause"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:text="@string/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickStop"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Timer timer = new Timer(1500);
      timer.runTimer();
  }
}
```

Код класса:

```
public class Timer extends Activity {
private int seconds;
private boolean running;
private boolean paused;


public Timer(int seconds) {
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

public void runTimer() {
    final TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
            int secs = seconds%60;
            String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, secs);
            timeView.setText(time);
            if (running) {
                seconds--;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
}

public void onClickStartPause(View view) {
    if (view.equals(R.string.btnStart)) {
        this.running = true;
    } else {
        this.running = false;
        this.paused = true;
    }
}

public void onClickStop(View view) {
    this.running = false;
    this.paused = false;
    this.seconds = 1500;
}
}
```

При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка:

```
05-06 16:34:15.131 31139-31139/com.hfad.simplefocus2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.hfad.simplefocus2, PID: 31139
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hfad.simplefocus2/com.hfad.simplefocus2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2071)
                                                                       at com.hfad.simplefocus2.Timer.runTimer(Timer.java:19)
                                                                       at com.hfad.simplefocus2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Почему  `Timer` наследуется от активити и не реализует никаких методов жизненного цикла, а так же не инфлейтит разметку через `setContentView()`. Где он должен взять ссылку на `TextView`  по вашему, если разметка никакая не подключена ?

Comment: @pavlofff
Timer это просто класс, объект которого создается в MainActivity. Я видимо не до конца понимаю, как все это правильно реализовать, чтобы в MainActivity создавался и запускался, при нажатии на кнопку, объект. В классе Timer лежит его описание и методы. Timer не активность ,а просто класс.

Comment: У вас же вполне очевидно написано `Timer extends Activity` - класс наследуется от класса активити. В общем вам не надо наследоваться от активити, а надо написать в этом классе геттер, который будет отдавать значения. Весь UI перенести в активити

Comment: @pavlofff Геттеры на 3 приватные переменные? Перенести UI в активити, а с разметки его в таком случае убирать?

Comment: Разметка в активити , из активити есть доступ к UI (этой разметке). `Timer` не имеет прямого доступа к UI, он должен передавать просто значения в активити, а та уже выводить их на экран. И тут геттерами не обойдешься, понадобится что то вроде хэндлера, чтобы значения обновлялись.

Comment: @pavlofff Что-то не особо все понял. Написать весь код в MainActivity было намного проще) Не является ли это плохим примером кода?

Comment: Если вам только отсчет времени нужен, то выносить таймер в отдельный класс не обязательно. Можете вот [пример посмотреть](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/)

Comment: начните изучать Андроид по какому-нибудь курсу, и не делайте больше таких глупостей. Чтобы объяснить, в чем у вас тут проблема, потребуется несколько часов, т. к. вы не изучили основы. Вам тут их описывать никто не собирается.

Comment: Да я понял свою глупость)